# How to find and replace string using REGEXP_REPLACE in postgresql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, regexp-replace

I have a table of email addresses:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts(
    email     VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO contacts VALUES    
    ('example.person@gmail.com'),
    ('example.person2@gmail.com'),
    ('example.person3@gmail.com');
```

How can I find and replace the email format so `example.person@gmail.com` -> `example.person_gmailcom@test.com`?

E.g:

```
UPDATE contacts
SET email = REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '@', '@test.com');
```

Results in `example.person@test.comgmail.com`

Playground here: https://dbfiddle.uk/GnIfomiO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably most simply done by splitting the email address in two on the `@`, keeping the part before it and replacing `.` in the part after it with nothing. Then you can just append `@test.com` to the result:

```sql
UPDATE contacts
SET email = SPLIT_PART(email, '@', 1) || '_' || REPLACE(SPLIT_PART(email, '@', 2), '.', '') || '@test.com';
```

Output for your demo:

```
email
example.person_gmailcom@test.com
example.person2_gmailcom@test.com
example.person3_gmailcom@test.com
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ILId-QB_)

Answer (score 1):

demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/0KWPVeAI

```
UPDATE contacts
SET email = REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '@', '_gmailcom@');

UPDATE contacts
SET email = REGEXP_REPLACE(email, '@.*$', '@test.com');
```

The regex pattern is **@ follow all the chars to end of string**

Comment: What if the email address is not `@gmail.com`?